# Tint of the image does not want to change

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I am trying to set a new color of the image while the cell of the UICollectionView was selected or deselected. Whenever i do not set a tint color of the image it is working, but i do not wanna have default `blue` color of it. So What I am doing is :

In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`  function, I am inicialazing my images with code :

```
 let borderWidth = itemBorder.frame.width
             let borderHeight = itemBorder.frame.height

             myImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: borderWidth - 1/4 * borderWidth, height: borderHeight - 1/5 * borderHeight))
             myImage.image = UIImage(named: myCollection[indexPath.row])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
             myImage.tintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
             myImage.center = CGPoint(x: tmpCell.bounds.width/2, y: tmpCell.bounds.height/2)
             myImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
             tmpCell.contentView.addSubview(myImage)
```

and so on in the didselected and deselected function :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let currentCell: UICollectionViewCell?
        switch collectionView {
        case myCollectionView:
            print("clicked")
            currentCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
                currentCell?.tintColor = UIColor.white

        case colorsCollectionView:
           break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let currentCell: UICollectionViewCell?
        switch collectionView {
        case vehiclesCollectionView:
            print("deselected")
            currentCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
            currentCell?.tintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
        case colorsCollectionView:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Could someone tell me whats wrong ? 
Thanks in advance!

Solution

**Solution**
Whenever i wanted to update the tint of the color i was pointing on the cell not on the image so basiclly only need to add this into selected or deselected method :

```
currentCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
            let image = currentCell?.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIImageView
            image.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are setting the `currentCell?.tintColor` but I suppose you will probably have to set the `currentCell?.vehicleImageView.image.tintColor`

Also I see your code as a bit confusing since you have `vehicleImage` (which should probably be named `vehicleImageView`) and `myImage` which is a `UIImage` which is being added as a subView to the contentView? I thought it was only possible to add subclasses of `UIView` as subviews.

I suggest you create an outlet called `myImageView` in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` to which you can set the `image.tintColor` and change `cell.myImageView.tintColor` in your `didSelect` and `didDeselect`

If you do not add them from the storyboard, you can still create a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` that has a property called `vehicleImageView`. You can set the frame and image of this as required in your `cellForRow`. Now you will have a property which you can refer to in your `didSelect` and `didDeselect` as `cell.vehicleImageView.image.tintColor`.

If you do not want to create a subclass that has a property, you will basically have to loop through all your subviews and find the image view and set the image `tintColor` there. Setting the `tintColor` of the `UICollectionViewCell` **WILL NOT** solve the problem. You will have to set it to the `imageView.image`

Hope that helps!

Comment: u are right, i vae not changed all names. Gonna do this!

Comment: The thing is i do not add them from a storyboard. My problem is in this lines ` currentCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
            currentCell?.tintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground`

Comment: You are right! I've solved my problem, I will edid my question as well

Comment: Great! All the best!